# iOS Simulator only takes up part of the window

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My iOS Simulator only takes up part of the window, which makes things like taking screenshots very annoying. What can I do to fix this?

This occurs for every device **except** for the iPad 2.

[image]

Comment: Cool-o-rama! Never seen that one before.

Comment: Did you try resetting the simulator?

Comment: Try resetting the simulator, or try pressing CMD+1, CMD+2 etc, which should try to resize your simulator.

Comment: Neither resetting nor resizing the simulator helped, unfortunately. My simulator has been like this since I downloaded Xcode a couple of months ago and have only now tried to see if there's a solution.

Comment: I've seen a couple reports of this but have yet to reproduce it myself.  Can you please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com with a full system profile?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happened to me as well. I would suggest to change the **Hardware** -> **Device** to another Device to check if the simulator resolves the problem by itself.

In addition to that you could try to **reboot** in the simulator (**Hadware** -> **reboot**)

> It worked for me, but I can`t guarantee that it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've found that the only device with the correct size is the iPad 2. Rebooting did not resolve the problem.

Comment: I wil be trying to find a way to solve this. If I find something I will edit my post :) BTW: Are you working with a retina screen?